# How can i get Last login user date time and update in user form in online CRM 2011

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

Hello i have created on field in user(systemuser) Form.so i need to show Last Login Date time in that field.so i have to write PlugIn/script or anything.so basically my question is i get the information from Audit View.but how can i write Plugin and on which entity.because i cant find the Entity Audit in Plugin Registration tool.if so then may be i can write the plugin on Create Audit and update it on User Form.

I have just tried in one sample like below but i cant find date field.but my question is where can i write plugin and update user form.

```
var query = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery("audit")
                    where (int)a["operation"] == 4 &&
                    a["objectid"] == "E39383B6-AFBB-45DD-9F4A-C140A03F1871"
                    select a;
```

how can i get that field from audit.

In short i want last login date and time for Login User..

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

CRM 2011 [doesn't support tracking when users login / logout](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm/thread/c4f0f216-922e-4c38-968a-68afd4b7c766/).  If you're running locally you'd have to hack together some sort of system that read IIS logs and then updates a custom field on the User entity itself...

Comment: yes but if you look at the this link it will say that it is possible but i am not sure how can i do this?http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/05/25/auditing-user-logon.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547448.aspx

Comment: do you know How can i fire PlugIn when User LogIn?